# Grunt won't process lesscss file

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, less, grunt-contrib-less

I am trying to concatenate a set of `.less` files into a big `.less` file, and then have it processed into a big `.css` file using Grunt's `grunt-contrib-less` module.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({
        concurrent: {
            target1: ['concat:lesscss'],
            target2: ['less']
        },        
        concat: {
            lesscss: {
                files: {
                    'server/static/css/big.less':
                        ['server/static/css/commons-reset-and-core.css',
                         'server/static/css/base.less',
                         'server/static/css/ads.less',
                         'server/static/css/ext.less']
                }
            }
        },
        less: {
            files: {
                'server/static/css/big.css':
                    'server/static/css/big.less'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concurrent:target1', 'concurrent:target2']);

};
```

The `big.less` is created properly, but the `big.css` file is not. Yet, Grunt returns

> Done, without errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to wrap it as here:

```
less: {
    development: {
       files: {
           'server/static/css/big.css': 'server/static/css/big.less'
       }
    }
},
```

I think that's required